# Allow to enter only 5 numbers before decimal in textbox

Tags: jquery-ui

How to restrict user can allow to enter only 5 numbers before decimal and 2 numbers after decimal in textbox, like (99999.99).

Answer (score 0):

use type is number, with maximum value and stepsize

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="100000" step="0.01">
```

Comment: editor: { type:"textbox",style: 'z-index:10000;position:relative;', cls:'com1',},